# how to use search on listView with selecting match items in android?

Tags: android, listview, search

I create a table in sqlDataBase as below and want to put `search` option on it.  I want to select items with custom color from ListView that match with the word of searchable panel. 
how can i do it?

MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private AddAdapter adapter;
    private DataBaseClass classDB;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

    public final static ArrayList<String> _id=new ArrayList<String>();
    public final static ArrayList<String> _name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public final static ArrayList<String> _info = new ArrayList<String>();

    private EditText search;

    public  String doneIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        classDB =new DataBaseClass(this);

  // search panel
        search= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_panel);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
       }
```

AddAdapter.class:

```
public class AddBankAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> Bid, Bname, Binfo;

public AddAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<String> id ,ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> info){
context=c;
Bid=id; Bname=name; Binfo=info;  
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Bid.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
   ...
}
```

what is the `getFilter()`?
how can I coloring the items?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, but you need to add the colors for the filtered elements.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: my problem is, why `getfilter()` method is not initialized for me?